# Click event firing twice or more after history.back() Phonegap

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

I have two html pages in phonegap. `index.html` and `second.html.`
I put all my script in head section.
In `index.html` page I put all my Jquery and Ajax codes. Here are some code snippets that I use to change page.

**Index.html**

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
            <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="widdiv=device-widdiv, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <title>
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css" />



        <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
         <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script>
        </head>
        function callAnothePage(check)
            {
                $.mobile.changePage('second.html', { dataUrl : "second.html?paremeter="+check, data : { 'paremeter' : check }, reloadPage : false, changeHash : true });
            }
        $(document).on('pageshow', "#second",function () {
                var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];;
                parameter = parameters.replace("paremeter=","");
                });
        $(document).on('pageshow', "#index",function () {
                $(document).on('click', "#news",function () { //Something Something  });
});
    $(document).on('pageshow', "#second",function () {
     $(document).on('click', "#back",function () {     

                history.back();
            });
    </script>


        <body>
        <!-- Home -->
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h3>
                   Title
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
              <img src="img/logo5.png" />

              <a data-role="button" id="news">News</a>

            </div> <!--content-->

            <div data-role="content">
            <div><span class="status"></span></div>

               </div> <!--content-->
        </div><!--page--> 
        </body>
        </html>
```

Something like this. And my

**second.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="widdiv=device-widdiv, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title>
    </title>

   </head>
   <body>
    <!-- Home -->
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-role="header">

            <div id="new_title">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="news_date" class="mybutton"></div>
            <br/>
            <div id="news_description"></div>
            <br/><br/>
            <a data-role="button" id="back" class="mybutton_back">Back</a>
        </div> <!--content-->
    </div><!--page-->

  </body>
</html>
```

So First time it works fine. All events works fine. It does some work using jquery after button click and goes to `second.html` page. After viewing `second.html` I came back using `history.back()` Then problem starts. All button clicks works twice. All ajax calls are working twice. If I go to second page again and came back, then events fire 3 times and so on. I think **Scripts** are loaded multiple times.

I tried `$.mobile.changePage()` to get back to `index.html`. But it gets worse. Then all `events` fail. No click events or ajax call works if I use that.

***How to stop this? How can I prevent script to load multiple times?

OR
Is there any way so that I can load pages entirely? I mean all previous scripts load will be forgotten?***

Comment: Please create a JSfiddle  for that.. for better understanding...

Comment: <input type="button" value="Go back" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1);return false;" /> You can use some alternative...

Comment: </head> is placed in wrong location...

Comment: @Purus Sorry for that. I missed while copy pasting different portions of the code. </head> tag is in right position in actual code.

Comment: @Coder <input type="button" value="Go back" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1);return false;" /> It's working same as history.back()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code had issue problem. It will execute many time if you click many time on button. Why? Because once you click on button, event click will execute 1, and next click it will execute 1 + 1 event click of previous, and so on 1 + 1 + 1 if you click many time, ... 
Solution to prevent event fire many time:
1. Use off() or one:

```
$('#back').off().on('click',function(){

});
$('#back').one('click',function(){

});
```

2. Use flag:

```
var flag = true;
$('#back').on('click',function(){
    if(flag){
        flag = false;
        //code here
    } 
});
```

And check [link](http://www.gajotres.net/prevent-jquery-multiple-event-triggering/) to see more.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution.

```
document.location = "index.html"
```

Using it to go in previous page, prevent events from firing twice. Can't explain why, but worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).on('click', "#back",function () {
           if(event.handled !== true)
           {
                $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "slide";                
                var href = $(this).attr("href");
                event.preventDefault();
                if ( event === "click" ) { return; }                      
                $.mobile.changePage(href);
           }
           return false;               
   });
```

Comment: nope, same result. Firing twice after going back to index.html